# Django - Decoding MIME Header with Base64 and UTF-8

Tags: django, utf-8, base64, mime

I am creating a web email interface to read IMAP accounts. I'm having problems decoding a certain email header.

I obtain the following From header (specific example from an event email):

```
('"=?UTF-8?B?QmVubnkgQmVuYXNzaQ==?=" <NOREPLY@NOREPLY.LOCKNLOADEVENTS.COM>', None)
```

I separate the first part:

```
=?UTF-8?B?QmVubnkgQmVuYXNzaQ==?=
```

According to some research, it's aparently a Base64-encoded UTF-8 header.

I tried to decode it using the Base64 decoder:

```
# Separate sender name from email itself
first_part = header_text[1:header_text.index('" <')]
print "First part:", first_part

import base64
decoded_first_part = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(first_part)
print decoded_first_part
```

But I obtain a

```
TypeError: Incorrect padding.
```

Can anybody help me figure out what's wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> import base64
>>> base64.decodestring('QmVubnkgQmVuYXNzaQ==')
'Benny Benassi'
```

But you probably want to use [a proper IMAP library](http://docs.python.org/2/library/imaplib.html) for doing this stuff.

Comment: Thank you. Simple and effective. I'm using impalib itself, but it doesn't take care of these UTF-8 headers for some reason, therefore the problem.

Comment: If you accept an answer, it's good etiquette to upvote as well.